# Is it considered bad practice to inject a controller into a view component in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a view component that needs to do some logic to determine some links to display.  The links need to pass some parameters to the containing controller so that it knows what to display.

I tried using `@Url.Action("Method", "Controller", new { param = "param" })` helper to generate a link, but inside the view component this helper does not know how to properly generate this URL.

Instead, in my Default.cshtml I'm generating the links like this:

```
<a asp-action="Navigate" asp-route-function="@function">@function</a>
```

I've injected the controller of the containing view into the view component and am using the following code in the view component:

```
public class FunctionSelectorViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
  private readonly ParentController parentController;

  public FunctionSelectorViewComponent(ParentController parentController)
  {
    this.parentController = parentController;
  }

  public IActionResult Navigate(string function)
  {
    return this.parentController.Navigate(function);
  }
}
```

This approach works, but it feels a little bit bad, since it makes the ViewComponent class dependent on the parentController.

Is there a better approach to solving this problem?

Comment: If you are injecting a Controller, it doesn't matter where, you are doing it wrong. Why do you even need a ViewComponent here?

Comment: There's some extra business logic in there (which is excluded from the sample code here because it is not relevant) which seems to make it a good fit for a view component.  This class has one responsibility - to generate the correct links for the user to click on.

Comment: Then extract that logic out into its own service and inject that into the component.

Comment: Besides what @Nkosi correctly said, the URL Helper should work correctly, also the Anchor Tag Helper, assuming you're not actually using that code with a typo `<a asp-action="Navigate" asp-route-function="@function"**"**>@function</a>`

Comment: "Then extract that logic out into its own service and inject that into the component." - I thought the whole point of View Components was to isolate exactly this type of logic in the class.

Comment: So how do I properly create a link that calls an action on a controller that I do not have a reference to?

Comment: With just `<a asp-action="ActionName" asp-controller="ControllerName">link text</a>` (note you are missing the controller in your example)

Comment: Please add that as an answer so I can mark it correct.  And you might want to add "Yes, it is bad practice to inject a controller into a view component" to that answer as well :).

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have seen your comment just after writing the answer. I know you deserve the answer as you first provided the solution in the comment. Thank you so much. By the way I have also added some explanation when a tag helper works without specifying the controller name explicitly and when not.

Comment: @TanvirArjel I went to sleep right after my last comment, so don't worry about it, good answer by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep in mind that injecting a Controller is always a bad idea, doesn't matter where. Controllers should only be there to handle requests.

The view returned by a `ViewComponent` is a part of view returned by the Action being called, but it is not directly a part of the Controller handling the request since `ViewComponent`s are meant to be reusable. The problem was that you did not specify the controller name in the Anchor Tag Helper explicitly and one cannot be inferred.
Remember, only the tag helpers in the views returned by the same controller's actions do not require the controller name explicitly. So you can generate the link here like in a view returned by controller method as follows:

```
<a asp-contorller="Parent" asp-action="Navigate" asp-route-function="@function">@function</a>
```